# How to remove ajax toolkit from website

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, ajaxcontroltoolkit

How can i remove the ajax toolkit from my website? i developed my website in .net 4.0 when i compile it in 2.0 and run it, it gets this error on page load.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.
```

I thinks its the Ajax that causes me that error because ajax is not present ing .net 2.0

I am not using ajax in my Website so its Okay for me to delete it or remove it from the current website.

**EDIT**
This is the assembly Load Trace:

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = PJLIMAIN\aslaure
LOG: DisplayName = AjaxControlToolkit
 (Partial)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/aslaure/Desktop/IACS References/PJLhuillier.IACS/PJLhuillier.IACS/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Users\aslaure\Desktop\IACS References\PJLhuillier.IACS\PJLhuillier.IACS\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\aslaure\Desktop\IACS References\PJLhuillier.IACS\PJLhuillier.IACS\web.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/aslaure/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/70cff49e/7a1e4609/AjaxControlToolkit.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/aslaure/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/70cff49e/7a1e4609/AjaxControlToolkit/AjaxControlToolkit.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/aslaure/Desktop/IACS References/PJLhuillier.IACS/PJLhuillier.IACS/bin/AjaxControlToolkit.DLL.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x8013101b). Probing terminated.
```

Comment: look in your web.config

Comment: @JohnSaunders what ill i look in the web configfile specifically? it doesnt contain anything just my connection string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove this line from top of aspx file :

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
```

Comment: @DanzaiVer also look at your Master page if you used master page

Comment: @DanzaiVer also make sure that your new build be successful

Comment: sir i searched the whole solution and there are no "ajax" term in it please se the problem again i edited some of it.

Comment: it is successful sir.

Comment: @DanzaiVer Did you searched for 'AjaxControlToolkit' keyword in all of proj?

Comment: @DanzaiVer also try rebuild all of proj

Answer (score 0):

Just delete this line from your aspx page and also clear the ajax control toolkit from your reference(check your reference)

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"
 Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
```